# Does Bitcoin Gold automatically appear in my ledger nano s wallet?

Tags: ledger-hardware-wallet, bitcoin-gold

How do I get Bitcoin Gold into the Ledger Nano S Bitcoin Gold (Segwit) wallet?

Comment: Have you downloaded the Bitcoin Gold Chrome app?

Comment: Yes,The Bitcoin Gold wallet is now in my Ledger Nano S. I downloaded the Ledger wallet chrome app, I went to 'Settings-Tools-Reset the application, and then went to the Blockchain (Segwit) and still no Bitcoin Gold in my wallet. Dont know what else to do. I thought the BTG would arrive in the wallet automatically.